# XCode Server doesn't automatically download provisioning profiles and code sign identities

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-server

I've updated my remote system to OS El Capitan and my XCode Server to 5.0.4.  Xcode version now is 7.0.1.

Since these upgrades, building my app with XCode Server results in the message

> No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a
>   provisioning profile

I copied the provisioning profile to the server myself, into directory /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles.

This worked but then I got the error:

> Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing
>   identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team
>   ID

The next step I took is exporting and importing the certificates as a .p12 file to the server. Now, When I do an integrate on the server the server keeps hanging on the integration-step building sources, signing product. At the end I receive the error, running task was terminated because it produced no activity for too long.

Does anyone know why XCode Server doesn't automatically download profiles and certificates anymore and how to resolve this???  thanks in advance!

Comment: have you updated in keychain access

Comment: I see my certificate and private key in system keychain access on my remote system. What do I have to update in Keychain Access?